# Monitor TryEnter logic

Tags: c#, thread-safety

I have a piece of code I only want to execute once, but it's possible to get several requests at the same time, more specifically, a document operation.

The logic is the first thread to arrive does the code and the others wait for the first one to finish and then all return.

Since this can happen to any document, I created a dictionary that holds the locking object for each document (by id)

```
private static readonly object LockFetchDocument = new object();
private static readonly Dictionary<int, object> DocumentLocks = new Dictionary<int, object>();

//Let's add the monitor for this document (this has to be thread-safe too)
lock (LockFetchDocument)
{
    if (!DocumentLocks.ContainsKey(docModel.DocumentId))
    {
        DocumentLocks.Add(docModel.DocumentId, new object());
    }
}

//let's aquire the Monitor for this document so we don't prefetch the same document at the same time
if (!Monitor.TryEnter(DocumentLocks[docModel.DocumentId]))
{
    //document is being exported, let's wait for it to end
    lock (DocumentLocks[docModel.DocumentId])
    {
        //document was exported, return
        return;
    }
}

//Monitor aquired
try
{
    //DO WORK
}
finally
{
    //Let's release the monitor for this document
    lock (DocumentLocks[docModel.DocumentId])
    {
        Monitor.Exit(DocumentLocks[docModel.DocumentId]);
    }
}
```

Is this logic good? In order to make the dictionary adding, I use another locker. But I get a Resharper warning that the Monitor.TryEnter is not inside synchronization block. Is it needed?

Comment: You have a race condition here: `Monitor.TryEnter(DocumentLocks[docModel.DocumentId])`. You might be reading and writing the `DocumentLocks` at the same time.

Comment: Instead of `try-finally` you should use `lock()`, it will do the same for you.

Comment: Also, I'd use `ConcurrentDictionary` class, it will save you some locking.

Comment: You may find useful `ReaderWriterLock` class (many threads can read, but only one write): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your overall idea is good, but there are some issues with your code:

- You shouldn't use `System.Threading.Monitor` and `lock()` to lock the same object twice at the same time.
- In the first part you are correctly locking when you use `DocumentLocks`, but later you access it without locks.

  ```
  private static readonly Dictionary<int, object> DocumentLocks = new Dictionary<int, object>();
  private static readonly object LockFetchDocument = new object();

  public static void ExportDocument(int ID)
  {
      object DocumentLocker;
      lock (LockFetchDocument)
      {
          // Only access DocumentLocks inside this block
          if (DocumentLocks.ContainsKey(ID))
          {
              DocumentLocker = DocumentLocks[ID];
          }
          else
          {
              DocumentLocker = new object();
              DocumentLocks[ID] = DocumentLocker;
          }
      }

      bool lockTaken = false;
      try
      {
          System.Threading.Monitor.TryEnter(DocumentLocker, ref lockTaken);
          if (!lockTaken)
          {
              // Export is already running, wait for it to finish then return
              System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(DocumentLocker, ref lockTaken);
              // When we return the finally block will still be executed and release the lock
              return;
          }

          // Do stuff
      }
      finally
      {
          if (lockTaken)
              System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(DocumentLocker);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: You are right, should not use lock when I can Enter the Monitor.

Answer (score 2):

I would slightly rebuilt it:

```
var lockTaken = false;
object gate = null;

//Let's add the monitor for this document (this has to be thread-safe too)
lock (LockFetchDocument)
{
    // acquire the gate only once from the dictionary.
    if (!DocumentLocks.TryGetValue(docModel.DocumentId, out gate))
    {
        gate = new object();
        DocumentLocks.Add(docModel.DocumentId, gate);
    }
}

try
{
    //let's aquire the Monitor for this document so we don't prefetch the same document at the same time
    Monitor.TryEnter(gate, ref lockTaken);

    if (!lockTaken)
    {
        //document is being exported, let's wait for it to end
        lock (gate)
        {
            //document was exported, return
            return;
        }
    }

    //Monitor aquired
    //DO WORK
}
finally
{
    //Let's release the monitor for this document
    if (lockTaken)
    {
        Monitor.Exit(gate);
    }
}
```

By using that approach you never have problems with dead-lock through not released monitors. Also the double lock in your last finally block has been gone. Last but not least, the multiple calls to the dictionary are gone, making it robust if anyone is going to manipulate it while you are on the run.

Comment: I like your solution but it should be if (!lockTaken)